# Bitwise Operators (And) in PHP. Getting weird answers

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

So I'm making this script that needs to get the integer from the & operator of two numers in PHP. So far I have managed it to work but with small numbers (<512). When I try to do do for example: 
`echo 65535 $ 2048;`
I get a result of 0, when it's supposed to be 2048. Any ideas why I am getting this result or how can I get the desired result?. Thank you In advance
I'm using PHP 5.5 and Ubuntu.

Comment: Where is `&` in `echo 65535 $ 2048;`? For my case `echo 65535 & 2048;` giving me result `2028`.

Comment: That's obviously a typo.

Comment: @Manwal, I assume you mean it gave you `2048`, yes?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I ment 65535 & 2048. And I also managed to solve it. Since I was getting the numbers I wanted to & from a resultset, they came in Strings instead of integer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is not the `and` operator, `&` is.

If you try:

```
echo 65535 & 2048;
```

you should get `2048` just fine, as I just did on http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/.

Answer (score 0):

When you try to run this:

```
echo 65535 $ 2048;
```

You will get this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting ',' or ';'
```

For my case code:

```
echo 65535 & 2048;
```

Giving output **2048**

> Note: You have typo there should be & inplace of $. because $ is not
> and operator but & is.

## [DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/26501134812f323fa8a673dd8148c2fe51cd039e)